# origin of the expression "proudly placed on our mantelpiece"

Tags: etymology, expressions

What is the origin of the expression "proudly placed on our mantelpiece"? In what context started to be used?

Comment: How can you identify the First use of a sentence? It's not an idiom

Comment: It's not an "expression". It's a verb phrase, and not idiomatic. As to when it was used for the first time, well, the only answer possible is "at some time in English history **after** there were mantelpieces on which things could be placed".

Answer (score 2):

Mantelpiece is the shelf on top of the fireplace.
Even if it's just a small electric fire it's the place that people display the important photographs and ornaments - because it's the centre piece of the room.

It's not a particular common idiom though

http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/2009/jan/03/mantelpieces-family-history